# eager loaded collection slow to query

Tags: laravel, collections

After updating the version of `Laravel` to `5.5` my eager loaded collection is now much slower to query.

My collection has quite a large amount of data eager loaded but this was not an issue before upgrading. However, I can consistantly show the code works with `laravel 5.4` but breaks in `5.5`

My query previously was this:

```php
$this->holidays->where('attributes.date', $date->format('Y-m-d'))->first();
```

Where `$this` references the collection.

However after upgrading to 5.5 this no longer worked and i had to change the syntax to this.

```php
$this->holidays->where('date', $date)->first();
```

I assumed this was due to the change in dates now being carbon objects.

With the original code, my page would load in approx 10 seconds after the change this now takes over a minute.

If I constrain the eager loaded holidays I can bring this time down but I would really like to find a way to have the same performance as before on the same data set.

Comment: Why aren't you upgrade directly to the newest version (6.0) of laravel?

Comment: Because 5.8 was the stable version at the time i went through the upgrade process and i don't want to introduce another version until i can resolve this issue.

Comment: I doubt it's due to the use of Carbon.  $date will be converted to and from Carbon exactly once in this query.  Try examining the SQL generated by the queries in each version.

Comment: Have you tried the ``->whereDate()`` function? I'm not sure why it's that slow in your case but I'm using the ``->whereDate()`` function for such a case and I've never noticed such performance issues.

Comment: @ChuckAdams as the collection data seems to be the same i think the SQL queries are the same. I will double check though.

Comment: @thmspl this is a collection i am querying and does not have that method that i am aware of

Comment: I'd agree that jumping to 6.0 is not wise, but have you tried it on 5.8?  And @thmspl, `whereFoo(bar)` is just Eloquent magic for `where('foo', bar)`

Comment: @ChuckAdams i am currently using 5.8. I have gone through my previous release tags at each major version of laravel from 5.1 to .5.8 and this issue only started after moving to 5.5 but has remained an issue through the later versions.